# Raspberry Pi 1 B vs. Raspberry Pi 2 B ASM speed difference

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have the following code:

```
for (short l = j; l < j + input->w_small; l = l + 4){
  add_b = k * input->w_big + l;
  add_s = (k - i) * input->w_small + l - j;

  __asm__ __volatile__(
      "ldr %%r1, [%1];"
      "ldr %%r2, [%2];"
      "usada8 %0, %%r1, %%r2, %0;"
      :"+r" (sad)
      : "r" (input->pic_big + add_b), "r" (input->pic_small + add_s)
      : "r1", "r2"
      );
}
```

This is part of an image processing algorithm. The application runs 29.24 seconds on RPi 1 B and 7.65 seconds on RPi 2 B resulting in 3.82x speed-up. The question is, why? I understand, that there is an architectural change between the models, but I didn't find any reference regarding USADA8, that it should be significantly faster on ARMv7. Any ideas?

P.S.: Don't get me wrong, I am perfectly happy with the results, just being curious :)

Comment: Are those times really for _just_ this loop (i.e. based on measurements immediately before and after), or do they include other code as well - there are an awful lot of potential code generation differences on top of the innate hardware differences, especially for any pure C loops or multithread-capable library code.

Comment: Good point. No, the times are for the whole code, but this it the most time consuming part.

Comment: what happens if you remove usada8?  or try other speed tests?  as already mentioned above and below, armv7 vs armv6, that right there could be the whole answer.  clock speeds are different.  cache sizes.  did you re-compile for each system or use the same binary, maybe the compiler did something different as well.   You could run bare metal and get the operating system out of the way, mess with config.txt and run at the same clock rates, disable the caches, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There may be many reasons, but the main ones are probably (according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi)):

- the core frequency is not the same (900MHz for model 2B and 700MHz
  for model 1B)
- The L1 cache of 2B is twice the size og the L1 cache in model 1B (16kB vs 32 kB). I suspect that L2 caches and generally speaking the cache hierarchy is also different.
- You might have a different [config](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) for both (you can tweak the frequencies of various things)

Comment: [From a bit of web-scouring](http://makezine.com/2015/02/02/eben-upton-raspberry-pi-2/), the 2836 apparently uses the Cortex-A7 integrated L2 cache, with 512KB, compared to the 2835  with just the ARM11's L1 and the shared 128KB external system cache (which supposedly is exclusive to the GPU on the 2836). That, and the fact that Cortex-A7 also has an stride-detecting automatic data prefetcher, likely makes a massive difference for array-walking code like this.